# Can someone explain this short line of code to me?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

```
bool stop = false;
           int f1 = 1;
           int f2 = 2;
           int f3 = 0;
           int sum = 2;
           while (!stop)
           {
               f3 = f1 + f2;
               sum += f3 % 2 == 0 ? f3 : 0; //THIS ONE
               stop = f3 > 4000000 ? true : false;//AND THIS ONE.
               f1 = f2;
               f2 = f3;
           }
```

What is that conditional operator? This is the first time I've seen anything like this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The line:

```
sum += f3 % 2 == 0 ? f3 : 0; //THIS ONE
```

is the same as:

```
if (f3 % 2 == 0)
  sum += f3;
else
  sum += 0;
```

which could of course be rewritten as

```
if (f3 % 2 == 0) sum += f3;
```

and the line

```
stop = f3 > 4000000 ? true : false;//AND THIS ONE.
```

is the same as

```
if (f3 > 4000000)
   stop = true;
else 
   stop = false;
```

Or better yet:

```
stop = f3 > 4000000;
```

Comment: `if (f3 % 2 == 0) sum += f3;` could also be rewritten as merely `if (!(f3 % 2)) sum += f3;` since 0 is a false value and non-zero is a true value.

Comment: @klouks: tyvm!
@Dav: you are correct, but I have never been a fan of mixing boolean operations and integers. This is however purely a question of taste, and usually has to do with how much contact one has with old-school C programmers. :-)

Comment: Neither of you are correct. There's no conversion between int and bool in C#. You're thinking of C, not C#.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me Eric. I never do that, so I didn't know it wasn't even legal in C#.

Answer (score 5):

The expression

```
x = c ? a : b;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (c)
    x = a;
else
    x = b;
```

Also, the statement

```
stop = f3 > 4000000 ? true : false;
```

is completely redundant, and can be simplified to

```
stop = (f3 > 4000000);
```

*(Paretheses added for clarity.)*

Comment: Which _could_ open up a way for an optimization/simplification on `do { ... } while (f3 <= 4000000);`

Answer (score 4):

It's called the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_operator).

Answer (score 2):

If the condition (stuff to the left of ? is true, then it uses the first (the one before :) if not it uses the second (stuff after :).

```
int res = someCondition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28VS.80%29.aspx

Another one u will probably see soon:

```
   SomeClass res = someVariable ?? valueIfSomeVariableIsNull;
```

---

**Update:** on the refactor route, you might want:

```
while (!isMoreThan4Million)
{
   f3 = f1 + f2;
   bool sumIsEven = f3 % 2 == 0;
   sum += sumIsEven ? f3 : 0;
   isMoreThan4Million = f3 > 4000000;
   f1 = f2;
   f2 = f3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28VS.80%29.aspx

it basically reads like this:

if this condition is true ? then do this : otherwise do this

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28VS.80%29.aspx

It's called the ternary operator. It will evaluate the value before the : if the expression on the left of the ? is true - otherwise it evaluates the value after the :

Answer (score 0):

it's more or less a compact equivalent of an if then:

```
(condition) ? ifConditionIsTrueUseThisValue : ifConditionIsFalseUseThisValue ;
```

commonly used to do a conditional value assignment:

```
variableName = (condition) ? valueIfConditionIsTrue : valueIfConditionIsFalse ;
```

simple stupid example to assign a value of x which ignores values below zero:

```
x = (x < 0) ? 0 : x ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As masterfully written as the original was, you could obfuscate it's intent further:

```
int sum = 2;
for(int f1 = 1, f2 = 2, f3 = 0; !((f3 = (f1 + f2)) > 4000000); f1 = f2, f2 = f3)
    sum += f3 * (~f3 & 1);
```

... or ... write it like a normal person would:

```
int f1 = 1;
int f2 = 2;
int f3 = 0;
int sum = 2;

while( f3 <= 4000000 )
{
    f3 = f1 + f2;
    bool even = (f3 & 1) == 0;
    if( even )
        sum += f3;
    f1 = f2;
    f2 = f3;
}
```

... or ... if you like it really simple:

```
int sum = 4613732;
```

Even after rewriting it twice I don't get what it does... what's the purpose of this anyway?

Answer (score -2):

predicate ? then : else